# Jquery Tools, range onSlide

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I can't seem to figure out how to use the onSlide event, and the forums at jquerytools don't seem to work

Basically, I'd like to get the current range value on slide, instead of onchange.

Here's what I have working for onchange, but I'd like to get the current value while sliding the range selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/rx3AJ/

The JS I've been trying:

```
$(function () {

      $("#slideshow img").each(function(index, element){$(element).attr("id", index+1);});    

      var count = $("#slideshow img").length;

      $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();
      $("#date p").text($("#slideshow img#1").attr("alt"));

      $(":range").rangeinput({
            precision: 0, value: 1, min: 1, max: count,
            onSlide: function() {
                console.log("you\'re sliding");
                //this is where i want to update do stuff on slide I think? but it won't work
                return true;
              }   
        });

      $(':range').bind('onSlide', function(){})
      $(":range").change(function(event, value) {
          //i'd like to do this onslide
          console.info("value changed to", value);
          $('#slideshow img').hide();
          $('#slideshow img#' + value).show();
          $("#date p").text($("#slideshow img#" + value).attr("alt"));
      });

  });​
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated because I have no clue...

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use jsfiddle because it doesn't include the jQuery tools library. Second, change your range input code to this:

```
$(":range").rangeinput({
    precision: 0, value: 1, min: 1, max: count,
    onSlide: function(event, i) {
        $('#slideshow img').hide();
        $('#slideshow img').eq(i).show(); 
        // the way you had works too, but you don't have to assign id's this way
        $("#date p").text($("#slideshow img").eq(i).attr("alt"));

    }   
});
```

And be sure to include jQuery tools (which includes jQuery)